# Java saving input in the text file

Tags: input, output

My problem is printwriter method. I don't know why it doesn't save text from the console to the text file. It should work but the only line that is saved in the file is "quit". I `m new to Java and this forum. Hopefully, someone will be able to help me. 
Greetings
Michal

```
public class Output3  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String line= "";
        try {
            PrintWriter ska = new PrintWriter("trial1");
            while(!linia.equals("quit"))
                linia = scanner.nextLine();
                ska.println(line);
                ska.flush();
                System.out.println("Message saved");
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen that you read from the input stream through the variable `linia` and write data from the variable `line` to your file? Have you tried writing using the following line?

```
ska.println(linia);
```